# Inhomogeneous system of DE in matrix form

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

I have got the following inhomogeneous systems of differential equations:

$$ \dot x = 2x + y + 3 e ^{t} $$
$$ \dot y = 4x - y $$

I have to write down in matrix form the corresponding homogeneous system of equations.

But I am stuck with the part of $3 e ^{t} $

Does anybody have a pointer?

Comment: That term makes the system not homogeneous. You don't use it for the matrix form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write this as the system

$$X'(t) = AX(t) + g(t) = \begin{pmatrix}2 & 1 \\ 4 & -1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}3 e^t \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$

You could then solve the homogeneous and non-homogeneous part using many different approaches.

If you are looking for theory and examples, see these [*notes*](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/Book%3A_Differential_Equations_for_Engineers_(Lebl)/3%3A_Systems_of_ODEs/3.9%3A_Nonhomogeneous_systems) or [*notes*](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/NonhomogeneousSystems.aspx) or [*notes*](https://math24.net/linear-nonhomogeneous-systems-differential-equations-constant-coefficients.html).

If you solve these, you would get

$$\begin{align} x(t) &= \frac{1}{5} c_1 e^{-2 t}+\frac{4}{5} c_1 e^{3 t}-\frac{1}{5} c_2 e^{-2 t}+\frac{1}{5} c_2 e^{3 t} -e^t \\
y(t) &= -\frac{4}{5} c_1 e^{-2 t}+\frac{4}{5} c_1 e^{3 t}+\frac{4}{5} c_2 e^{-2 t}+\frac{1}{5} c_2 e^{3 t} -2 e^t \end{align}$$